# Complete Specs for Mid-2010 iMac & Early-2011 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, upgrade, memory, cpu

OK, so here I am. I've searched anywhere I could but definitely couldn't find what I was looking for.

I'm thinking of performing some sort of upgrade (e.g. SSD or memory or CPU) and I'm trying to figure out the *exact* specs regarding the CPU.

That's all I know :

- My 21.5" iMac has a Core i3 @ 3.06 GHz.
- My 13" MacBook Pro has a Core i5 @ 2.3 GHz.

But, what about the exact models? (I was trying to perform a benchmark comparison the other day between the two, and [couldn't figure out what to choose](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/)...)

Any ideas?

---

**Also :** do you have any idea which of those parts (specifically the cpu) **IS** upgradeable? and up to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well's that what I managed to discover using GeekBench... (well, I mean regarding the CPU models) :

13" MacBook Pro - Early 2011 :

- **CPU :** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2415M @ 2.30GHz
- **Memory :** 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3

21.5" iMac - Mid 2010 :

- **CPU :** Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 540 @ 3.07GHz
- **Memory :** 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3

---

I still have to check about the upgradeability, though...

Answer (score 0):

- [iMac (21.5 and 27-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP588)
- [iMac: How to remove or install memory](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1423)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP619)

AFAIK the CPU is not replaceable on any current Mac model.

Comment: Thanks for the info, though I've already had a look at Apple's resources, which surprisingly *omit* the exact CPU models. (Please, have a look at my answer, to see what I mean). As for whether CPUs are replaceable, I've seen quite a lot of people saying they did it, so I'll guess I'll have another look around...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.lowendmac.com for tech specs, and much more, on any model.

Here are the links for your systems.  Unfortunately it list no upgrades available for your iMac.

[iMac (Mid 2010)](http://www.lowendmac.com/imacs/imac-mid-2010.html)

[13″ MacBook Pro (Early 2011)](http://www.lowendmac.com/macbookpro/13in-macbook-pro-feb-2011.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Everymac.com](http://everymac.com) is *the* site for information, specs, everything, on  ... every Mac.

Bookmark it.